# Play/Pause Button working Offline but not Online

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, audio

I'm not very good with java and I got this code after researching for a simple play/pause button for a music loop on a website. It works fine testing it offline, but after uploading to the FTP Server it doesn't play the audio in any browser and I get SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Heres the code:

```
<style>
button{ border:none; cursor:pointer; outline:none; }
button#playpausebtn{
    background:url(images/sound_on.png) no-repeat;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
</style>
<script>
var audio, playbtn, seek_bar;
function initAudioPlayer(){
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "newsongs/Geboren__xsm2.mp3";
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.play();
    // Set object references
    playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
    // Add Event Handling
    playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause);
    // Functions
    function playPause(){
        if(audio.paused){
            audio.play();
            playbtn.style.background = "url(images/sound_on.png) no-repeat";
        } else {
            audio.pause();
            playbtn.style.background = "url(images/sound_off.png) no-repeat";
        }
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
</script>
```

Comment: use `onload` event on audio before calling play()

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just found my own error. The comment tags were making it not load right!